# Nonseparable Banach spaces in probability theory

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory, banach-spaces

I am trying to understand the topologies of the Skorohod space of [càdlàg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g) functions. I found the following sentence in one paper.

> The supremum norm converts the Skorokhod space into a *nonseparable* Banach space, what is always disadvantageous in probability theory.

As far as I understand, the nonseparability of the Skorokhod space equipped with supremum norm is one of the main reasons to investigate different topologies of this space (for example, the metric separable topology $J_1$ introduced by Skorokhod).

My questions are as follow: why is a nonseparable Banach space always disadvantageous in probability theory; what kind of problems do we have to deal with when we have a nonseparable Banach space?  Some examples or references would be really great.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You often need Polish spaces. For example the probability measure on the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of Polish spaces are always Radon measures.